# есть ли быстрые способы формирования страницы по рабтое с БД для юзера?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Как написать простую форму по созданию/редактированию БД?(MySQL,PHP). Заходит юзер(всегда 1) на страницу, подгружает существующие данные из БД, добавляет/редактирует их и сохраняет в БД. Как такое обычно реализовывается? Мое решение:

- По нажатию submit, JQuery получает JSON из файла, которые формирует
  данные из БД. (Причем приходится отправлять id элементов из таблицы БД,
  чтобы правильно записывать обратно) Все данные из БД вставляются в поля на странице.
- После редактирования, нажав другую кнопку submit, методом POST забираю данные со страницы и сохраняю в БД.

Получилось как-то громоздко, так ли это чаще всего делается? Или лучше при нажатии вместо JQuery, использовать php. То есть удалить существующие HTML теги и сформировать заново их с данными из БД? Или так не делается и есть более быстрые решения?

Comment: Методы "с помощью jQuery" (правильнее назвать его "с помощью AJAX") и "с помощью PHP" идентичны, различаются разве что пользовательским опытом + для аякса немного больше кода получится. А так вы всё правильно описали.

Comment: Примеров можно много привести, вот один из наиболее наглядных: https://www.thesoftwareguy.in/simple-address-book-with-php-and-mysql-using-pdo/ . Там есть и демо, и исходный код, никаких классов, все доступно и понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчет правильности..Сейчас на дворе уже 2017 год, и конечно Javascript уже позволяет выполнять множество операций на стороне пользователя и логично использовать его мощь в отображении данных, а обработку данных через API возложить на backend.

С другой стороны для минимального простого приложения, которое делает обычный POST - это не всегда надо.

Классическое приложение для работы с БД обычно называют **CRUD** - по первым буквам стандартных операций, Create, read, update and delete (Создание чтение обновление удаление).
Это как гамма в музыке - любое приложение состоит из этих базовых элементов.
В нашем случае это веб-страница, которая выводит список записей в БД в виде списка (R), позволяет добавлять в список новые записи (C),редактировать их (U) и удалять (D).

С помощью подобных библиотек (crud) расположенных на **github** такое приложение реализуется буквально в несколько строчек. Также очень удобно то, что с помощью подобного кода можно редактировать любые таблицы, меняя только названия таблицы и поля.

Будем считать, что это один из универсальных способов формирования приложения, которое занимается 4 операциями. Возможно, вы мало знакомы с ООП и благодаря этому поймете принципы формирования библиотек и их прелестей, когда код может использоваться повторно.

Я рекомендую Вам использовать фреймворки и с помощью них начать реализовывать подобный функционал на основе архитектуры MVC. Реализация подобных проектов на фреймворках занимает минимальное время. Смотрите Lavarel, Symfony и т.д.

Comment: ПРОСТУЮ форму CRUD можно прекрасно написать и без фреймворков. Я бы даже сказал, что ее надо написать ДО изучения фреймворков и можно написать даже до знакомства с классами.

Comment: @labris Вопрос был все-таки про быстрые способы формирования подобного функционала и я думаю, что автор подобные манипуляции уже проводил.

Comment: Кто сумел поставить Laravel, таких вопросов уже не задает :)